# How can I keep an image/link visible vertically on page?

Tags: css

How can I keep an image visible in browser window on a very long page vertically? (not centered as it is now) Here is the page that has the situation: http://designs-and-more.com/Apparel_Designs.html Note that as you scroll down you will see the links but I want them be visible at all times. Anybody have any help? If anyone knows of a link to an example that would be great since my programming skills are very, very basic. thanks greatly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The old-school way was to use frames. I believe most websites are not doing this these days (generally menus, side bars, etc. scroll away along with the page content) as they consider keeping the frames design to be undesirable for user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have checked your website. You have to add CSS speciality to your declarations.

```
vertical-aling: top;


.dsR37 {
    background-image: url("images/but_Home_BG.png");
     vertical-aling: top;
}
```

Example for home link, your other menu declarations different, so you have to add each other.

Comment: thanks, I did that and it did put it at the top of the cell but when I scroll down the browser page it disappears. I want it to to stay visible even if the browser page is scrolled down. I'm not much of a coder so I need a sample or exactly where to put the code. I figured out that you meant align (not aling) thanks.

Comment: Yeah noticed about later about it. I will try to provide example code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for CSS fixed positioning. Here's a demo from David Walsh's site: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/css-fixed-position.php

Google "css fixed positioning" and you'll find some demos on how to 'pin' the side nav to be visible no matter where the user scrolls.

Comment: I checked that page and that would work for the vertical but not for the horizontal (unless a flush left website) since my website is centered and a fixed width puts the image in different places horizontally. There has to be an answer out there somewhere.